# Custom Styling for Electron Right-Click Menu

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Currently, my code (see below) is giving the OS Right-click menu. My goal is to add custom stylings, such as changing the background color, or adding padding. I want to know if that is possible with my current code or if I have to use a different Package.

Here is my code:

```js
const remote = electron.remote
const Menu = remote.Menu
const MenuItem = remote.MenuItem

const sceneCardElements = document.querySelectorAll('.scene-card')

let rightClickPosition = null

const sceneCardMenu = new Menu()
const sceneCardMenuItem1 = new MenuItem({
  label: 'Edit',
  click: () => {
    remote.getCurrentWindow().loadFile('./sceneSettings.html')
  }
})
sceneCardMenu.append(sceneCardMenuItem1)

sceneCardElements.forEach((sceneCardElement) => {
    if (sceneCardElement == null) return
    sceneCardElement.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        rightClickPosition = {x: e.x, y: e.y}
        sceneCardMenu.popup(remote.getCurrentWindow())
      }, false)
})
```

here is a screenshot of what it returns:

[My Code's Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOrG3.png)

Here is a screenshot of what I want to do (example from Discord):

[An Example Software's Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCV65.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up using a library called [tippy.js](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/) and using their right-click menu [template](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/misc/)

here is the final code for anyone looking at this post in the future:

```js
// Get the Element you want to Right-Click
const element = document.querySelector('#rightClickable')

// Define the Tippy.js Rightclick Element
const instance = tippy(element, {
  // Get the Template you made into JS
  content: document.getElementById('rightClickMenuTemplate').innerHTML,
  placement: 'right-start',
  trigger: 'manual',
  interactive: true,
  arrow: false,
  offset: [0, 0],
  allowHTML: true,
});

// Add the Event Listener
element.addEventListener('contextmenu', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  instance.setProps({
    getReferenceClientRect: () => ({
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
      top: event.clientY,
      bottom: event.clientY,
      left: event.clientX,
      right: event.clientX,
    }),
  });

  instance.show();
});
```

```html
<!-- Right Click the Text Below -->
<p id="rightClickable">Right Click Me!</p>

<!-- Right-Click Menu Template Used by Tippy.js -->
<div id="rightClickMenuTemplate" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
  <strong>Hi from the Right-Click Menu</strong>
</div>

<!-- Import Tippy.js -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@6"></script>
```